# Computation of density of product of independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given $X, Y$ two independent random variables which are uniformly distributed in $(0, 1)$.

How can the density of $XY$ be calculated?

My idea is to first compute the joint density of $(X, XY)$. But how to continue?

The joint density for $(X, Y)$ equals $f_{X,Y} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \text{exp}(- \frac{x^2+y^2}{2})$, right?

Thanks for any hint(s).

Comment: $f(x,y)$ you stated is the joint density of two independent standard gaussian...in the exercise you stated they are iid uniformly in (0;1). Please explain what you have to do. Moreover, what is the role of Z in this exercise?

Comment: Oh, I edited the question - there are only X and Y, sorry. The goal is to calculate the  density of XY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given X,Y two independent random variables which are uniformly distributed in (0, 1).

If $X,Y$ are iid uniformly distributed in $(0;1)$ their joint density is 1 over the unit square.

To derive $f_{U}(u)$ first state the following system

$$\begin{cases}
u=xy\\
v=x
\end{cases}\rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=v\\
y=\frac{u}{v}
\end{cases}$$

Calculate the jacobian which results $|J|=\frac{1}{v}$

thus the joint density is

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\frac{1}{v}$$

To find $f_U$ simply integrate in $dv$ which results

$$f_U(u)=\int_u^1 \frac{1}{v}dv=-\log u$$

and this because

$$y=\frac{u}{v} \in (0;1)\rightarrow 0<\underbrace{u<v<1}_{\text{integration range for } v}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explication really helps! Thanks also for writing all the steps, I really appreciate this! 
The Jaconian is (0 ; 1/v), right?

Comment: @StMan :the jacobian is the determinant of the matrix of the derivatives:


$$\text{det}\left[\begin{matrix}
    \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}} & \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}  \\
    \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} & \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} \\
    \end{matrix}\right]=\text{det}\left[\begin{matrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    \frac{1}{v} & -\frac{u}{v^2} \\
    \end{matrix}\right]=-\frac{1}{v}$$

It has to be taken in absolute value thus $|J|=\frac{1}{v}$

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for this additional explication! :)